# getline function definition in K&R

Tags: c, for-loop, c-strings, getchar

The following is getline implementation in K&R on page 29 ,

```
# define MAXLINE 1000
int getLine(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c ,i ;
    for(i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c!= '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if(c == '\n'){
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
    
}
```

I don't understand why we need to do "i < lim - 1" here in the for loop. For correct indexing, why doesn't " i < lim " suffice ?

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Be careful if you try to implement this to explore how it works - [POSIX defines a `getline()` function with a different prototype](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/getline.html):  `ssize_t getline(char **restrict lineptr, size_t *restrict n, FILE *restrict stream);`

Comment: @AndrewHenle — I agree, but it looks like the OP has worked around that by using camelCase for the function name.

Comment: Better coding style might be: `int getLine(char s[], size_t size) { size_t strlength = size-1; ... for(size_t i=0; i<strlength; i++)`. Teaching how to write readable code wasn't K&R's forte... they rather subscribed to the "most operators in a single expression wins a price" philosophy...

Answer (score 5):

The function is going to build a string (stored in the array specified by the parameter `char s[]`) that is a sequence of characters terminated with the zero terminating character `'\0'`.

So one element of the array is reserved for the terminating zero character that is appended to the character array before exiting the function

```
s[i] = '\0';
```

For example if the variable `lim` is equal to `5` then you may enter in the array no more than `4` characters in the range of indices `[0, 3]`. In this case (if all `lim-1` characters will be filled) in the last element of the array there will be written the terminating zero character `'\0'` at position `4`.

Comment: But then why say limit is 5 when you just want 4 elements. I looked at the source code for the standard library getline() function. I see an if statement as : if((len + 1) < 256) { ... }.  It looks quite similar to what we are doing here ; i < lim - 1 but I fail to see the logic ..

Comment: @ShashankChoudhary There is clear written in my answer that one element is reserved for the zero terminating character because the function returns a string.